# shell: HERE document - mark of EOF does not work in function

Tags: bash, shell

Having this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function func () {
   cat <<- EOF
   some stuff
   EOF
   return
}
```

Gives

```
 ./a: line 7: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file
 (wanted `EOF') ./a: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What's wrong with my HERE mark?

Comment: Try EOF at column 0 (not indented)

Comment: @John3136 have edited, actually with dash before, it enables indenting

Comment: Quoting [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net): When using <<-, you can only indent with tabs.